# How can I use Lucene in cmd

Tags: lucene, cmd

I am trying to use lucene on the Windows' command line as given in this [link](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description).

I have created the CLASSPATH variable for all four mentioned `.jar` files, but after that, when I run the command:

`java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs C:/lucene/src`

it returns the following error:

`could not find or load main class org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles`

I dont know what's wrong with it... Can anybody help me out?
I am a student and just a beginner. 
Thanks

Comment: Please post the exact command you run .. my suspicion is that you're not using the `-classpath %CLASSPATH%` command line option on your java commands.  Alternately, you're apparently on windows, and I wonder if you used a Linux tutorial to build the classpath.  The syntax for building pathing is different on Windows vs. Unix.

Comment: my command was **java -classpath C:\lucene-4.2.1\core;C:\lucene-4.2.1\demo;C:\lucene-4.2.1\analysis\common;C:\lucene-4.2.1\queryparser;**

Comment: Interesting.  Usually classpaths point to JAR files, but they don't have to if the directory you point to contains class files.  Does one of these directories have `org\apache\lucene\demo\IndexFiles.class`?

Comment: no. this no directory contains 'org\apache\lucene\demo\IndexFiles'

Comment: There's your problem.  You need to have the lucene jars on the classpath.

Comment: i chanced upon this. hope you find it useful. see https://github.com/javasoze/clue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue, you need to include the CLASSPATHs in your command (if its not in environment vars).  So it should be:

```
java -classpath C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0\core\lucene-core-5.1.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0\queryparser\lucene-queryparser-5.1.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0\analysis\common\lucene-analyzers-common-5.1.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0\demo\lucene-demo-5.1.0.jar org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0
```

And to search, you'd do:

```
java -classpath C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0\core\lucene-core-5.1.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0\queryparser\lucene-queryparser-5.1.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0\analysis\common\lucene-analyzers-common-5.1.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene-5.1.0\demo\lucene-demo-5.1.0.jar org.apache.lucene.demo.SearchFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if Lucene would have a start scripts packaged to play araonud with ... I've created an indexfiles.cmd in my installation root directory with this content:

```
java -classpath core\lucene-core-7.4.0.jar;queryparser\lucene-queryparser-7.4.0.jar;analysis\common\lucene-analyzers-common-7.4.0.jar;demo\lucene-demo-7.4.0.jar org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles %*
```

and another one called searchfiles.cmd:

```
java -classpath core\lucene-core-7.4.0.jar;queryparser\lucene-queryparser-7.4.0.jar;analysis\common\lucene-analyzers-common-7.4.0.jar;demo\lucene-demo-7.4.0.jar org.apache.lucene.demo.SearchFiles %*
```